# How to store data/result in in chrome extension and how to use use of setTimeout so that it will be called only once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, in which I want to run a webgl demo for specific time and then get the frames per second for that page and then load a new webgl demo and then store the frames per second and continue this for 4-5 webgl demos and store the result as pass and Frames Per Second or fail if the demo is not loaded.

I am using setTimeout to run the for specific time and then clearing it to stop the first demo and load the second one. But in my extension it keeps loading the second one and not able to clearTimeout for second demo and go to third one.
Could anybody help me get the right way to do it.

background.js

```
//var duration = 30;
//var start_time = new Date();

var frames_per_demo = {};
var URL_1 = "http://david.alloza.eu/WebGL/morphing.html";
var URL_2 = "http://webglsamples.org/blob/blob.html";
var URL_3 = "http://webglsamples.org/dynamic-cubemap/dynamic-cubemap.html"
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
chrome.tabs.create({ url: URL_1 });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {

if (msg.message === "TC_1") {
    window.clearTimeout(msg.timer_1);
    frames_per_demo.TC1_Result = msg.frames_1;
    window.alert("tc1 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo));
    chrome.tabs.update({ url: URL_2 });

}
if (msg.message === "TC_2") {
    window.clearTimeout(msg.timer_2);
    frames_per_demo.TC2_Result = msg.frames_2;
    window.alert("tc2 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo));
    chrome.tabs.update({ url: URL_3 });

}
if (msg.message === "TC_3") {
    window.clearTimeout(msg.timer_3);
    frames_per_demo.TC3_Result = msg.frames_3;
    window.alert("tc3 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo)); 
}
});
```

content.js:-

```
console.log("content script started");

var tc1_timer = setTimeout(function(){
console.log("Starting morphing demo");
var frames_morphing_demo = document.getElementById("framerate").innerHTML;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "TC_1", "frames_1":      frames_morphing_demo, "timer_1": tc1_timer});
}, 10000);


var tc2_timer = setTimeout(function(){
console.log("Starting blob");
var frames_blob_demo = document.getElementById("fps").innerHTML;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "TC_2", "frames_2": frames_blob_demo, "timer_2": tc2_timer});
}, 20000);

var tc3_timer = setTimeout(function(){
console.log("Starting cubemap");
var frames_cubemap_demo = document.getElementById("fps").innerHTML;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "TC_3", "frames_3": frames_cubemap_demo, "timer_3": tc3_timer});
}, 30000);
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "store FPS data",
"version": "1",
"browser_action":
{
    "default_icon": "Test.png"
},
"background":{
 "scripts": ["background.js"],
 "persistent": true
 },
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": false
}
],
"permissions": ["tabs", "storage"],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

---

The whole idea is to run all demos one after the other and if any demo is not loaded properly, display/store fail else Pass and the FPS data.
Could anybody help in this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you navigate (for instance, with `chrome.tabs.update({ url: URL_2 });`, but that happens of every navigation) the JS contexts attached to the page are completely torn down. Your content script does not survive.

As such, your content script just *restarts* (since it's re-injected after the navigation). Also, timers are not shared across pages, so you can't cancel a timer from background.

Also, since it's set to load into *every page*, it makes the browsing unusable:

- If any page happens to have a `#framerate` or `#fps` element, it will signal your extension and the tab will be hijacked
- If a page has no such elements, your script just fizzles with a fatal error on trying to access `null.innerHTML`

A good strategy would be keeping the state in the background page itself, and also inject the scripts programmatically instead of injecting it everywhere.

So:

1) Remove the content scripts section from the manifest, and add URLs of your tests to `"permissions"` (required for injection). By the way, you *don't* need the `"tabs"` permission.

2) Make a generic script that works on both pages:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var fps_element = document.getElementById("framerate") ||
                    document.getElementById("fps");
  if(fps_element) {
    var fps = fps_element.innerHTML;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      {"message": "FPS", "frames": fps});
  } else {
    // No such element found; fail somehow
  }
}, 10000);
```

3) Keep track of the state and inject scripts as needed in the background:

```
var test = 0;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  if(test == 0) { // Only react if test is not running yet
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: URL_1 }, function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});
    });
    test = 1;
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
  if (msg.message === "FPS") {
    switch(test) {
      case 1:
        frames_per_demo.TC1_Result = msg.frames;
        // You really shouldn't use `alert`, since it blocks execution;
        // Try chrome.notifications? Or use console for debugging.
        alert("tc1 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo));
        test = 2;
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, { url: URL_2 }, function(tab) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});
        });
        break;
      case 2:
        frames_per_demo.TC2_Result = msg.frames;
        alert("tc2 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo));
        test = 3;
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, { url: URL_3 }, function(tab) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});
        });
        break;
      case 3:
        frames_per_demo.TC3_Result = msg.frames;
        alert("tc3 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo));
        test = 0;
        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
        break;
      default:
        // Unexpected, fail somehow
    }
  }
});
```

I left the code with the structure you used; `switch` can be thrown out for a better code if you switch to using arrays of URLs and test results.

Failing is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Hi Xan, Thanks a lot for the neat implementation and the idea. But chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"}) doesn't work if I remove the content_script section from the manifest.json. But as you rightly pointed out, if I keep the content_script section, it does execute the script but keeps the first instance again and again. Any idea how I can get rid of it ?

Comment: You forgot to add host permissions (step 1). Without them, you're not allowed to inject.

Comment: I have added the permission for the URLs in manifest.json as below.

Comment: Oh, damn, you're right. It's my fault. I forgot to inject the script the first time. See the edit in `chrome.tabs.create`

Comment: {
     "name": "Chrome graphics testing",
     "version": "1",
     "browser_action":
    {
    "default_icon": "Test.png"
    },
    "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
    },
   "permissions": [
   "tabs", 
   "storage", 
   "http://david.alloza.eu/WebGL/morphing.html", 
   "http://webglsamples.org/blob/blob.html", 
   "http://webglsamples.org/dynamic-cubemap/dynamic-cubemap.html" 
   ],
   "manifest_version": 2
   }

Comment: **Never** add long code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your post if you need to add code. But I hope it's resolved now.

Comment: Hi Xan, Thanks a lot for the instant response. It collects the fps for first URL only and it always add the first URL FPS to the fps collector object. "frames_per_demo" always stores the first URL FPS for all three links.

Comment: I think the content script is still always running and that's why the FPS result is not getting stored for 2nd and 3rd URL. And also the 2nd and 3rd URLs are not getting loaded. Any direction in which I should think of to fix the issue ?

Comment: I think this is because I forgot `break;` statements at the end of cases. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Xan, The problem still exists. As after updating the first URL using [chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});] it doesn't call the content script anymore. And I am not able to see the console log for content script as the page has been re-loaded with second URL. I tried increasing the delay as well, but still after first URL update, I am not able to collect the FPS value and even the URL update.  Any thoughts how to collect the FPS ?

Comment: Hi Xan, I used beow code to make it work for collecting FPS. I am not able to vote up your answer as I am not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 1:
    // Try chrome.notifications? Or use console for debugging.
    frames_per_demo.TC1_Result = msg.frames;
    //alert("tc1 " + JSON.stringify(frames_per_demo));
    test = 2;
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, { url: URL_2 }, function(tab) {
      **setTimeout(function(){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});},10000);**
    });
    break;
```